# How can I search for a particular string in a folder full of files and import it?

Tags: r

I have a folder full of files with filenames such as these.

```
[1] "ts.01382800.crest.csv" "ts.01383500.crest.csv" "ts.01384500.crest.csv" "ts.01386000.crest.csv"
 [5] "ts.01387000.crest.csv" "ts.01387400.crest.csv" "ts.01387420.crest.csv" "ts.01387450.crest.csv"
 [9] "ts.01387500.crest.csv" "ts.01387908.crest.csv"
```

I need to do one operation again and again. Basically search for a particular string (Say, **1382800**), find the filename with the match and import it. Please note, the name may not be exact match as the preceding zero may not exist sometimes.

Currently, I am importing a list of the files in the folder using **list.files**, using **grep** on that list to find a filename, then re-constructing the file path and importing it. There must be an easier way to do it.

Comment: Use the pattern argument in list.files.

Comment: `ls <- list.files(path='~/',pattern="1382800")` this filter all the data contains "1382800"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code filter all the data contains  `1382800`

```
 ls <- list.files(path='~/',pattern="1382800")
```